# Why is covering map a fibration? Incorrect proof?

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is on [page 66, Tom Dieck's](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/diecktop.pdf)

> A covering $p:E \rightarrow B$ is a fibration.

What concerns me is its proof.

The proof is claims is suffices to consider local lifts - how?

---

On page 63, (Prop 3.1.3) there is a uniquely lifting from $f:X \rightarrow B$ to $F:X \rightarrow E$, give that $X$ is **connected**.

---

**Suppose** we can lift locally. (Definition below) **Then** we may piece up all the local fibrations by **uniqueness**. But $X$ is not necessarily connected here. Only $I$ is.

---

So how does the **piecing** work?

---

> Local lifiting:  on $V \times I \subseteq X \times I$, with respect to an initial condition $a:V  \times \{0 \} \rightarrow E$, $h:V \times I \rightarrow B$, then exists $H$ ,
>   $$  H: V \times I \rightarrow E, pH=h, Hi=a.$$

Comment: If $X$ is not connected, then can you not just restrict to each of its (path) components and proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X$ is irrelevant here. Given $a : X \to E$ and a homotopy $H : X \times I \to B$ such that $p \circ a = H_0$ we find an open covering $\{ V_\alpha \}$ of $X$ and local lifts $G^\alpha : V_\alpha \times I \to E$ of $H \mid_{V_\alpha \times I}$ such that $a \mid_{V_\alpha} = G^\alpha_0$. We have to show that $G^\alpha$ and  $ G^\beta$ agree on $(V_\alpha \times I) \cap (V_\beta \times I)$. This is the same as showing that $G^\alpha \mid_{\{ x \} \times I} = G^\beta \mid_{\{ x \} \times I}$ for all $x \in V_\alpha \cap V_\beta$.

But Proposition 3.1.3 applies for $X' = \{ x \} \times I$, $f  = H \mid_{\{ x \} \times I} \to B$ and $F_0 = G^\alpha \mid_{\{ x \} \times I}, F_1 = G^\beta \mid_{\{ x \} \times I}$ because $F_0(x,0) = G^\alpha(x,0) = a(x) = G^\beta(x,0) = F_1(x,0)$.

Note that what we have used here is known as *unique path lifting*.

Comment: sorry for bothering you again from old post, but I have some questions on relative $K$-theory, and I believe you would be an expert in this area - please, if you have time look at my two new questions.

Comment: Although I am not an expert, I shall have  a look!

Comment: Thank you very much Paul!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot answer the essential parts of your questions. Perhaps I could do more if I would read the whole text, but I do not have the time to do so. I shall make a few comments, perhaps they are helpful.